# Chain rule proof (Duistermaat & Kolk)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, chain-rule

In proving the chain rule, Duistermaat and Kolk use $$\lim_{x \to a}\psi(f(x))\phi(x) = \lim_{x \to a} \psi(f(x))\lim_{x \to a}\phi(x) = (Dg(f(a))Df(a)$$ where $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(y)$ are the linear functions from Hadamard's lemma for $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ respectively.

My question regards the first equality: $$\lim_{x \to a}\psi(f(x))\phi(x) = \lim_{x \to a} \psi(f(x))\lim_{x \to a}\phi(x)$$ Is the limit of the product of two operator valued functions the product of the limits of the functions?

The book claims it follows from the limit of the inner product of two functions is equal to the inner product of their limits, i.e. $$\lim(f_1,f_2)=(\lim f_1,\lim f_2)$$ Yet this doesn't apply here at all.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The result that for sequences $x_n \rightarrow x$, $y_n\rightarrow y$ 
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_ny_n =xy$$
Along with the result that:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = c \, \text{iff} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(a_n) = c \, $$ $$\forall \{a_n\} \, \text{s.t} \,a_n \neq a \vee a_n \rightarrow a$$
This immediately implies

> If $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = c$$$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = d$$
>   Then $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)g(x) =cd$$

As we are given that the limits of $\psi, \phi$ exist, the result follows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was quite comforting; the linear operators are bounded so your answer naturally applies. The problem is just the inner product part. What is the "inner product" here?

Comment: For functions $f,g$ defined on an interval $[a,b]$ the inner product $(f,g)$ is defined as $\int_a^b fg \, dx $

Comment: Ok, but my functions are operator valued functions $\phi : \mathbb{R^m} \to Lin(\mathbb{R^m},\mathbb{R^n})$ and $\psi : \mathbb{R^n} \to Lin(\mathbb{R^n},\mathbb{R^p})$. Does the same inner product still apply?